# How to calculate aggregated mean based on time window in Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

For the problem, I want to calculate the mean for a particular member with a time window of 3 years. For example for the following data frame:

| member_id | Feature 1 | Feature 2 | Feature 3 | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.1 | 0.5 | 0.2 | 1/2/20 |
| 1 | 0.2 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 1/2/18 |
| 1 | 0.3 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 1/2/16 |
| 1 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.1 | 1/4/17 |
| 2 | 0.4 | 0.1 | 0.4 | 1/2/18 |
| 2 | 0.5 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 1/2/15 |

Taking into consideration of member_id = 1, there are different dates of admissions but we would want to consider only those whose time-window lies in the 3-year gap.

So, for the first row, the member_id = 1 with the date 1/2/20 would have the window from 1/2/20 - 1/2/17. Thus, while taking the aggregate value for the feature, rows 1,2, and 4 would be selected excluding the 3rd row where the date is 1/2/16.

I want the first row values to be like:

| member_id | Feature 1_mean | Feature 2_mean | Feature 3_mean | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.13 | 0.33 | 0.2 | 1/2/20 |
| 1 | 0.2 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 1/2/18 |
| 1 | 0.3 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 1/2/16 |
| 1 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.1 | 1/4/17 |
| 2 | 0.4 | 0.1 | 0.4 | 1/2/18 |
| 2 | 0.5 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 1/2/15 |

Now, similarly the same for row values 2 and 3 and so forth. The best way I thought would be to, first group by the members and then sort the data. After that iterate through each row calculating the mean.

I had written a sample code but it grouped it by the date causing multiple additional rows.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
results = dict()
for start in df['date']:
    end = start.date() - relativedelta(years=3)
    screen = (df.date <= start) & (df.date >= end)  # screen for 3 years of data
    singles = df.loc[screen, ['Feature 1', 'Feature 2', 'Feature 3' , 'member_id']]  # screen for 3 year window member_id by groups
    x = singles.groupby('member_id').mean()
    results[start] = x
results = pd.concat(results)
```

What is the best way to achieve the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proceed as follows:

1. Define a function to get mean features for particular row from
   the current group, for the required period:

   ```
   def getRowMeans(row, grp):
       dTo = row.Date
       return grp[grp.Date.between(dTo - pd.DateOffset(years=3), dTo)]\
           .loc[:, 'Feature 1' : 'Feature 3'].mean()
   ```

   The idea is:

   - the current object is a *row*, from a group of rows (for some
     *member_id*),
   - for the operations below the whole group must also be known,
     so it is another parameter of this function (*grp*),
   - from *grp* take rows for 3 years preceding from the *Date* from
     the current row (including this date),
   - from these rows take all 3 *Feature* columns and return their means.
2. Define a function, to be called for each group of rows (for some
   *member_id*), returning a copy of this group with all *Feature* columns
   replaced with their means (generated by *getRowMeans*):

   ```
   def FeaturesToMeans(grp):
       means = grp.apply(getRowMeans, axis=1, grp=grp)
       rv = grp.copy()
       rv.update(means)
       return rv
   ```

   The first step is to compute feature means.

   In order not to alter the original group, the object to be finally
   returned (*rv*) must be created as a **copy** of the original group.

   Then it is updated with the just computed *means*.
   Note however that *update* operates **in place** and does not return any
   result.

   The returned object is the updated group.
3. Generate the actual result, as a new DataFrame:

   ```
   result = df.groupby('member_id', group_keys=False).apply(FeaturesToMeans)
   ```

The result, for your sample data, is:

```
   member_id  Feature 1  Feature 2  Feature 3       Date
0          1   0.133333   0.333333       0.20 2020-01-02
1          1   0.200000   0.233333       0.20 2018-01-02
2          1   0.300000   0.200000       0.20 2016-01-02
3          1   0.200000   0.200000       0.15 2017-01-04
4          2   0.450000   0.100000       0.30 2018-01-02
5          2   0.500000   0.100000       0.20 2015-01-02
```

Comment: Thank you Valdi_Bo! This was really helpful but I have been required to calculate for every admission date. So, like the first row is for the admission date 1/2/20 to 1/2/17. But the admission in the second row is on the date 1/2/18, so the average date range for it would be from 1/2/18 to 1/2/15. I have to move down each row and for a particular member and date combination calculate the average for 3 years data window. A little complicated.

Comment: I created a totally new answer, taking into account your comment.

Comment: Valdi_Bo, thank you! This is the output that was required.